# The entity type is not part of the model, EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-5

I am trying to update my repository to EF5 but have encountered a few errors. I've taken a look around stackoverflow for similar errors discovered a few questions/answers but unfortunately the same answers didn't resolve my issue.

This is my error:

```
The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

This is my DbContext class:

```
public abstract class WebModelContext : DbContext
{
    public WebModelContext()
        : base("WebConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

This is my context class that inherits my `WebModelContext` class:

```
public class AccountContext : WebModelContext
{
    private DbSet<User> _users;

    public AccountContext()
        : base()
    {
        _users = Set<User>();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
    }
}
```

This is my repository class:

```
public abstract class IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : WebModelContext, new()
{
    private T _context;

    protected T Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    public IRepository() {
        _context = new T();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~IRepository() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my AccountRepository class:

```
public class AccountRepository : IRepository<AccountContext>
{
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return Context.Users.ToList();
    }

    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        return Context.Users.Where(u => u.Name == username).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public User CreateUser(string username, string password, string salt, int age, int residence)
    {
        User user = new User
        {
            Name = username,
            Password = password,
            Salt = salt,
            RoleId = 1,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Locked = false,
            Muted = false,
            Banned = false,
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
        };
        Context.Users.Add(user);
        return Context.SaveChanges() > 0 ? user : null;
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF may not be able to pick up the entity types you have declared. Override the `OnModelCreating` and add the `User` entity to model.

```
public class AccountContext : WebModelContext
{
    private DbSet<User> _users;

    public AccountContext()
        : base()
    {
        _users = Set<User>();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried doing this just now and I encounter the same error. I originally added your code but VS said it wasn't overriding the OnModelCreating from DbContext so I replaced virtual with override. After doing that I added a breakpoint to the line `modelBuilder.Entity<User>();` but it didn't hit the breakpoint and still gave the same error.

Comment: @SHTester Try stopping and starting local ASP.NET Development Server/IIS

Comment: okay have done, still the same error, i'll try rebooting the machine.

Comment: Amazing! This really should help. Is there another User class hanging around somewhere?

Comment: Hi, Eranga! What might be the cause for "EF may not be able to pick up the entity types you have declared"? I thought, that having DbSet property should add entity to model...

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem with EF 5... What Ive done was to delete all files created by tt files and re-create them again... every thing was working again!

Answer (score 0):

Your table model name is wrong. set the correct name when sates in Sql server.
return View(db.tblEmployees.ToList());   **error line.....**

go Model and duble click ur model name than matching with table name like (tblEmployees)

your error is solve