# The entity type <class> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity, ef-model-first

This is a MODEL first approach. I have already researched this extensiely and have not come up with an answer. I have tried all the suggestions at the following links:

This appears to be the same problem but with no resolution
[The entity type <classname> is not part of the model for the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983108/the-entity-type-classname-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)

These are the links I have already researched so please don't answer as duplicate of ----
[EF 4.1 Code First error - The entity type SomeType is not part of the model for the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634392/ef-4-1-code-first-error-the-entity-type-sometype-is-not-part-of-the-model-for)
[The entity type is not part of the model, EF 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560966/the-entity-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-ef-5)

Here is the EDMX (Abbreviated for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
<!-- EF Runtime content -->
<edmx:Runtime>
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="Insight_Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"    ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="Insight_ModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="vwCompanyHeader" EntityType="Insight_Model.Store.vwCompanyHeader" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="vwCompanyHeader">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Name] AS [Name], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Active] AS [Active], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Creator] AS [Creator], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Created] AS [Created], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Modifier] AS [Modifier], 
  [vwCompanyHeader].[Modified] AS [Modified]
  FROM [dbo].[vwCompanyHeader] AS [vwCompanyHeader]</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
      <EntitySet Name="vwWorkOrderHeader" EntityType="Insight_Model.Store.vwWorkOrderHeader" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="vwWorkOrderHeader">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Active] AS [Active], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Name] AS [Name], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Creator] AS [Creator], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Created] AS [Created], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Modifier] AS [Modifier], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Leader] AS [Leader], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[LeadTakenDate] AS [LeadTakenDate], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[ProjectName] AS [ProjectName], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[WorkOrderStatus] AS [WorkOrderStatus], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[WorkOrderSubStatus] AS [WorkOrderSubStatus], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[WorkOrderType] AS [WorkOrderType], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[WorkOrderSubType] AS [WorkOrderSubType], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[WorkOrderPriority] AS [WorkOrderPriority], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[RefNumber] AS [RefNumber], 
  [vwWorkOrderHeader].[Request] AS [Request]
  FROM [dbo].[vwWorkOrderHeader] AS [vwWorkOrderHeader]</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="vwCompanyHeader">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
      <Property Name="Active" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Creator" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" />
      <Property Name="Created" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Modifier" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" />
      <Property Name="Modified" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="vwWorkOrderHeader">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Active" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15" />
      <Property Name="Creator" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" />
      <Property Name="Created" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Modifier" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" />
      <Property Name="Modified" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Leader" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" />
      <Property Name="LeadTakenDate" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="ProjectID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="ProjectName" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15" />
      <Property Name="WorkOrderStatus" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" />
      <Property Name="WorkOrderSubStatus" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" />
      <Property Name="WorkOrderType" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" />
      <Property Name="WorkOrderSubType" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" />
      <Property Name="WorkOrderPriority" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" />
      <Property Name="RefNumber" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="25" />
      <Property Name="Request" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1500" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="Insight_Model" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="Insight_Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="false">
      <EntitySet Name="CompanyHeaders" EntityType="Insight_Model.CompanyHeader" />
      <EntitySet Name="WorkOrderHeaders" EntityType="Insight_Model.WorkOrderHeader" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="CompanyHeader">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Type="String" Name="Name" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="Boolean" Name="Active" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Creator" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Created" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Modifier" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Modified" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="Int32" Name="ID" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="WorkOrderHeader">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Type="Int32" Name="ID" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="Boolean" Name="Active" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Creator" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Created" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Modifier" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Modified" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Leader" Nullable="false" MaxLength="51" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="DateTime" Name="LeadTakenDate" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="Int32" Name="ProjectID" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="ProjectName" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="WorkOrderStatus" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="WorkOrderSubStatus" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="WorkOrderType" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="WorkOrderSubType" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="WorkOrderPriority" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="RefNumber" MaxLength="25" Nullable="false" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Request" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1500" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
    </EntityType>
    </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
    <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="Insight_ModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="Insight_Entities">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="CompanyHeaders">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Insight_Model.CompanyHeader">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="vwCompanyHeader">
            <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Modified" ColumnName="Modified" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Modifier" ColumnName="Modifier" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Created" ColumnName="Created" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Creator" ColumnName="Creator" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Active" ColumnName="Active" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
      <EntitySetMapping Name="WorkOrderHeaders">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Insight_Model.WorkOrderHeader">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="vwWorkOrderHeader">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Request" ColumnName="Request" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="RefNumber" ColumnName="RefNumber" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="WorkOrderPriority" ColumnName="WorkOrderPriority" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="WorkOrderSubType" ColumnName="WorkOrderSubType" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="WorkOrderType" ColumnName="WorkOrderType" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="WorkOrderSubStatus" ColumnName="WorkOrderSubStatus" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="WorkOrderStatus" ColumnName="WorkOrderStatus" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ProjectName" ColumnName="ProjectName" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ProjectID" ColumnName="ProjectID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="LeadTakenDate" ColumnName="LeadTakenDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Leader" ColumnName="Leader" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Modified" ColumnName="Modified" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Modifier" ColumnName="Modifier" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Created" ColumnName="Created" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Creator" ColumnName="Creator" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Active" ColumnName="Active" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
      </EntityContainerMapping>
  </Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
```

The repository code:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Repository(Of T As {Class, IEntity})
Implements IRepository(Of T)

#Region "Attributes"
Private objectContext As IDatabaseContext
Protected objectSet As IDbSet(Of T)
#End Region

Public Sub New(objContext As IDatabaseContext)
    objectContext = objContext
    objectSet = objectContext.Set(Of T)()
End Sub
Public Function FindAll() As IQueryable(Of T) Implements IRepository(Of T).FindAll
    Return objectSet
End Function

Public Function FindWhere(predicate As Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of T) Implements Interfaces.IRepository(Of T).FindWhere
    Return objectSet.Where(predicate)
End Function

Public Function FindById(id As Integer) As T Implements IRepository(Of T).FindById
    Return objectSet.Single(Function(o) o.ID = id)
End Function

Public Sub Add(newEntity As T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Add
    objectSet.Add(newEntity)
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(entity As T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Remove
    objectSet.Remove(entity)
End Sub

Public Function Count(Optional predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)) = Nothing) As Integer Implements IRepository(Of T).Count
    Return If((predicate Is Nothing), objectSet.Count, objectSet.Where(predicate).Count)
End Function

Public Function Exist(Optional predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)) = Nothing) As Boolean Implements IRepository(Of T).Exist
    Return If((predicate Is Nothing), objectSet.Any, objectSet.Where(predicate).Any)
End Function
End Class
```

The DatabaseContext code:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports Insight.DataLayer.Interfaces
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class DatabaseContext
Inherits DbContext
Implements IDatabaseContext

Const defaultConnectStringName = "Insight_Entities"

Public Sub New()
     Me.New(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(defaultConnectStringName).ConnectionString)
End Sub
Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    MyBase.New(connectionString)
    MyBase.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
    MyBase.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
End Sub
Public Overloads Sub SaveChanges() Implements Interfaces.IDatabaseContext.SaveChanges
    MyBase.SaveChanges()
End Sub

Public Overloads Function [Set](Of T As Class)() As System.Data.Entity.IDbSet(Of T) Implements Interfaces.IDatabaseContext.Set
    Return MyBase.Set(Of T)()
End Function
End Class
```

And the 2 class files:

WorkOrderHeader:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Data.Services.Common

Partial Public Class WorkOrderHeader
Inherits DataTransferObjectHeaderBase

Public Sub New()

End Sub
Public Sub New(iID As Integer, sName As String, bActive As Boolean, sCreator As String, dtCreated As DateTime, sModifier As String, dtModified As DateTime, sLeader As String, dtLeadTaken As Date, iProjectID As Integer, sProjectName As String, sWorkOrderStatus As String, sWorkOrderSubStatus As String, sWorkOrderType As String, sWorkOrderSubType As String, sWorkOrderPriority As String, sRequest As String)
    Me.New(iID, sName, bActive, sCreator, dtCreated, sModifier, dtModified, sLeader, dtLeadTaken, iProjectID, sProjectName, sWorkOrderStatus, sWorkOrderSubStatus, sWorkOrderType, sWorkOrderSubType, sWorkOrderPriority, "", sRequest)
End Sub
Public Sub New(iID As Integer, sName As String, bActive As Boolean, sCreator As String, dtCreated As DateTime, sModifier As String, dtModified As DateTime, sLeader As String, dtLeadTaken As Date, iProjectID As Integer, sProjectName As String, sWorkOrderStatus As String, sWorkOrderSubStatus As String, sWorkOrderType As String, sWorkOrderSubType As String, sWorkOrderPriority As String, sRefNumber As String, sRequest As String)
    ID = iID
    Name = sName
    Active = bActive
    Creator = sCreator
    Created = dtCreated
    Modifier = sModifier
    Modified = dtModified
    Leader = sLeader
    LeadTaken = dtLeadTaken
    ProjectID = iProjectID
    ProjectName = sProjectName
    WorkOrderStatus = sWorkOrderStatus
    WorkOrderSubStatus = sWorkOrderSubStatus
    WorkOrderType = sWorkOrderType
    WorkOrderSubType = sWorkOrderSubType
    WorkOrderPriority = sWorkOrderPriority
    RefNumber = sRefNumber
    Request = sRequest
End Sub

<DataMember()> _
Public Property Leader() As String
    Get
        Return _leader
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _leader = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _leader As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property LeadTaken() As Date
    Get
        Return _leadTaken
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        _leadTaken = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _leadTaken As Date

<DataMember()> _
Public Property ProjectID() As Int32
    Get
        Return _projectID
    End Get
    Set(value As Int32)
        If (_projectID <> value) Then
            _projectID = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private _projectID As Int32

<DataMember()> _
Public Property ProjectName() As String
    Get
        Return _projectName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If (_projectName <> value) Then
            _projectName = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private _projectName As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property WorkOrderStatus() As String
    Get
        Return _workOrderStatus
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _workOrderStatus = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _workOrderStatus As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property WorkOrderSubStatus() As String
    Get
        Return _workOrderSubStatus
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _workOrderSubStatus = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _workOrderSubStatus As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property WorkOrderType() As String
    Get
        Return _workOrderType
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _workOrderType = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _workOrderType As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property WorkOrderSubType() As String
    Get
        Return _workOrderSubType
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _workOrderSubType = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _workOrderSubType As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property WorkOrderPriority() As String
    Get
        Return _workOrderPriority
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _workOrderPriority = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _workOrderPriority As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property RefNumber() As String
    Get
        Return _refNumber
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _refNumber = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _refNumber As String

<DataMember()> _
Public Property Request() As String
    Get
        Return _request
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _request = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _request As String

End Class
#End Region
```

CompanyHeader:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Data.Services.Common


<DataServiceKey("ID")> _
<MetadataTypeAttribute(GetType(CompanyHeader.CompanyHeaderMetadata))> _
Partial Public Class CompanyHeader
Inherits DataTransferObjectHeaderBase

Friend NotInheritable Class CompanyHeaderMetadata

    'Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
    Private Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Active As Boolean

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ID As Integer

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Created As DateTime

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Creator As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Modified As DateTime

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Modifier As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Sub New()

End Sub
Public Sub New(iID As Integer, sName As String, bActive As Boolean, sCreator As String, dtCreated As DateTime, sModifier As String, dtModified As DateTime)
    ID = iID
    Name = sName
    Active = bActive
    Creator = sCreator
    Created = dtCreated
    Modifier = sModifier
    Modified = dtModified
End Sub
End Class
```

Unit Test Code:

```
<TestMethod()> _
Public Sub WorkOrderServiceTests_TestConnectivityThruService5()
    Dim woService As New DatabaseContext
    Dim woHeaders = New Repository(Of WorkOrderHeader)(woService)
    Dim woTests = New Repository(Of WorkOrderTest)(woService)
    Dim coHeaders = New Repository(Of CompanyHeader)(woService)
    Assert.IsTrue(woHeaders.Count <> 0)
End Sub
```

Things I have tried to resolve the issue:

1) Checked database - Both queries return data correctly.
    select * from vwWorkOrderHeader
    select * from vwCompanyHeader

2) Deleted WorkOrderHeader from the EDMX then recreated it from database.

3) MOQed out the DBContext to make sure that it isn't the service query doing something funny. This correctly returns the object, so it means that it is something at the context level or below.

4) Stepped through both tests to ensure that they use the same method of building the context - Thy do.

4) Stepped through both tests to ensure that they use the same method of building the repository - Thy do.

5) The only difference is during the following Function of DatabaseContext:

```
Public Overloads Function [Set](Of T As Class)() As System.Data.Entity.IDbSet(Of T) Implements Interfaces.IDatabaseContext.Set
    Return MyBase.Set(Of T)()
End Function
```

The WorkOrderHeader code has the following in the watch for MyBase.Set(Of T)()

```
{System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Insight.Model.WorkOrderHeader)} System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Insight.Model.WorkOrderHeader)
```

The CompanyHeader code has the following in the watch for MyBase.Set(Of T)()

```
{SELECT   [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],   [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active],   [Extent1].[Creator] AS [Creator],   [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created],   [Extent1].[Modifier] AS [Modifier],   [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified],   [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]  FROM (SELECT        [vwCompanyHeader].[ID] AS [ID],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Name] AS [Name],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Active] AS [Active],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Creator] AS [Creator],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Created] AS [Created],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Modifier] AS [Modifier],        [vwCompanyHeader].[Modified] AS [Modified]       FROM [dbo].[vwCompanyHeader] AS [vwCompanyHeader]) AS [Extent1]}   System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Insight.Model.CompanyHeader)
```

I am at a complete loss on this one and am entering my 3rd day of working on the same problem. I am hoping that some fresh eyes on the problem might see an error that I have made or point me in a direction of testing the problem that I have not thought of.

UPDATE:

I removed the service code to ensure it was something in the DBContext. I have isolated the service out of the equation so that only the repositories are being used and they are all using the same DatabaseContext, so it can't be anything related to the connection string. I verified that in the Model Browser under Insight_Model/EntityContainer:Insight_Entities/Entity Sets/WorkOrderHeaders exists and that under Insight_Model/Entity Types/WorkOrderHeader exists. It almost appears as though the DatabaseContext isn't even attempting to query the conceptual model for the entity set.

Answer (score 23):

After 3 (4) days (depending on how you view days, I separate days by when I sleep and not necessarily when the sun goes down/comes up), I found the answer. In the EDMX file above, I have a column named LeadTakenDate, in the WorkOrderHeader class, I used the field name LeadTaken. This was a stupid error on my part.

How can this benefit you possibly? Here is how I resolved the problem:

First I isolated the problem to exactly one area by MOQing out parts to see how far down the rabbit hole the problem was. Once I figured out the problem was in the DatabaseContext, I wrote a test case that created a working and a non working use case. This isolated the problem and allowed me to test theories to fix it quicker. I tried a thousand different things before trying to use the EF 5.x persistance ignorant poco generator. I commented out all of my code in the WorkOrderHeader class and copied the generated code in. Reran my tests and they worked, so I started uncommenting my properties and commenting out the generated code then rerunning my test until I hit the appropriate property.

The error message is cryptic enough that is can be very difficult to trouble shoot.

Comment: Aaron well done for such a long and detailed question, edits, updates and answer. Sorry nobody else bothered to mark you up. I did!

Comment: For the effort and the community care alone I've just awarded both of you a point! Cheers guys and keep up the good work!

Comment: i have done exactly the same mistake and i spent two hours figuring out and finally when i was reading your first three lines then i thought wait a minute let me look my poco classes and there you go ...i see the culprit... i had my poco classes as an `Id` and in my database I changed to `CampusId` that throws me off so badly and i have learn my mistake...

Comment: So in your case the problem was incorrect property name? If that is the case then this error message is very misleading... :( I'm experiencing the same error and can not find what's behind this error message...